# Convert String in the Parenthesis in the URL To Query Parameters: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to convert the string in `{}` in search URL to query parameters which would help users capture search terms in web analytics tools.

Here's what I am trying to do, Let's say

**Search URL is:**

> example.com/search/newyork-gyms?dev=desktop&id=1220391131

**User Input will be:**

```
var search_url_format = '/search/{city}-{service}
```

**Output URL:**

> example.com/search?city=newyork&service=gyms&dev=desktop&id=1220391131

The problem is when is use the regex `{(.*)}` it captures the whole string `{city}-{service}`.

But I what I want is `[{city},{service}]`.

The URL format can also be like

> search/{city}/{service}/
>
> search/{city}_{service}/

What I have tried is for a single variable.

It returns correct output.

Eg: `URL:/search/newyork`

User Input: `/search/{city}`

Output: `/search/newyork?city=newyork`

URL: `/search-germany`

User Input: `/search-{country}`

Output: `/search-germany?country=germany`

```js
var search_url_format = '/search/{city}' //User Enters any variable in brackets
var urloutput = '/search/newyork' //Demo URL

//Log output

console.log(URL2Query(search_url_format)) //Output: '/search/newyork?city=newyork'

function URL2Query(url) {
  var variableReg = new RegExp(/{(.*)}/)
  var string_url = variableReg.exec(url)

  var variable1 = string_url[0]


  //Capture the variable 
  var reg = new RegExp(url.replace(variable1, '([^\?|\/|&]+)'))
  var search_string = reg.exec(urloutput)[1]


  if (location.search.length > 0) // if no query parameters
  {
    return urloutput + "?" + string_url[1] + "=" + search_string
  } else {
    return urloutput + "&" + string_url[1] + "=" + search_string

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two things:
parenthesis to match groups and you use .* which includes "{" sign.
So can use match instead of exec like this:

```
var search_url_format = '/search/{city}-{service}' //User Enters any    
var variableReg = new RegExp(/({\w+})/g)
var string_url = url.match(variableReg); // [{city}, {service}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably assume your "variable" will be alphanumeric instead of any character. With this assumption "{", "-", "_" etc will be punctuation.

so your grouping regexp could be `/({\w+})/g`.

```
//example 
const r = /({\w+})/g;
let variable;
const url = '/search/{city}-{service}';
while ((variable = r.exec(url)) !== null) {
 let msg = 'Found ' + variable[0] + '. ';
 msg += 'Next match starts at ' + r.lastIndex;
 console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: this won't show all matches but 2 times city in your example! you are missing /g in our regexp

Comment: Yes @laurent,  /({\w+})/g is the exact requirement in my case.